# 'setText' is deprecated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, deprecated, settext

Hey guys,
So i'm building an app combining Table View and Navigation Controller into my Tab Bar application and while it's compiling, I bumped into an error saying: 'setText' is deprecated

This is the section of my code that got this error:

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.text = [glossaryArray objectAtIndex:row]; // Right here is the problem
```

So hopefully anyone can help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cell.textLabel.text` instead.

Answer (score 1):

change cell.text to cell.textLabel.text

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a look at the API documentation? It was 10 seconds to find out after looking for "text" in UITableViewCell:

> The text of the cell. (Deprecated in
>   iOS 3.0. Use the textLabel and
>   detailTextLabel properties instead.)